# How to pass parameters to a (.sh) script that has Spawn command?

Tags: unix, command, expect, spawn

### I have the following little script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 90
set ip [lindex $argv 0]
set username [lindex $argv 1]
set password [lindex $argv 2]
set commands "sudo du -sh /var/tmp"
set regexp ".*"
set failonmatch "false"

if {[string trim $regexp] == ""} {
    set regexp ".*"
}
if {[string trim $failonmatch] == ""} {
set failonmatch "false"
}

log_user 0

spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $username@$ip $commands
...
```

---

(with Expect method after the spawn for the pass).

I want to run the command on another device (say IP 111.23.44.33).

How can I run the command with specific IP, username and pass? I mean, what command should I put to specify the arguments

I'm new to Unix and Expect, Thanks for your help!!

### Edited, this the expect code that I have (in case):

```
expect {
    timeout {
            send_user "Timeout connecting to device.\n"
            close
            wait
            exit 1
    }
    eof {
        send_user "Could not connect to device.\n"
        wait
        exit 1
    }
    -re "(.*refused)" {
        send_user "Connection to device refused.\n"
        wait
        exit 1
    }
    "*assword*:" {send "$password\r"}
}

expect {
    timeout {
            send_user "Timeout executing command on device.\n"
            close
            wait
                    exit 1
    }
    full_buffer {
            append outcome $expect_out(buffer)
            exp_continue
    }
    eof {
        append outcome $expect_out(buffer)
        puts $outcome
        if {"$failonmatch" == "false"} {
            if {[regexp $regexp $outcome]} {
                wait
                exit 0
            } else {
                wait
                exit 1
            }
        } else {
            if {[regexp $regexp $outcome]} {
                wait
                exit 1
            } else {
                wait
                exit 0
            }
        }
    }
    -re "(^.*assword*:)" {
            send_user "Unable to login to device.\n"
            puts $expect_out(buffer)
            close
            wait
            exit 1
    }
}
```

---

Thanks!!

Comment: Just because a file ends with ".sh", that doesn't mean it's a bash script. The shebang line tells the OS it's an expect script.

Comment: Oh thanks for the info! I will update the title and the tag then

Answer (score 0):

We can see from the code that the parameters are read from the `$argv` list:

```
set ip [lindex $argv 0]
set username [lindex $argv 1]
set password [lindex $argv 2]
```

[expect](/questions/tagged/expect) is an extension of the [tcl](/questions/tagged/tcl) language. The `argv` variable is [documented here](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/tclvars.htm).

To invoke the expect program with your parameters:

```sh
/path/to/expect/program 1.2.3.4 username 's3cretpa$$word'
```